# Is there a faster way to update a json array than by looping through it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, react-native, expo

Until expo lets me use Realm databases ive decided to go with Json and asyncstorage. The source data originates from Json anyway so for this app it makes sense to leave it as json.

I have a flatlist with the json displayed. To the left of each item in the list is a star icon.

When I touch each item in the list the star will go solid to indicate it has been pressed. Press it again, the icon will be an outline of a star to indicate it has been de-selected.

The `onpress` function looks like this symbols is the name of the JSON data the JSON data has 3 keys... symbol, name and iconName. Symbol is the item in the flatlist that is touched.

```
onPressListItem = ( symbol ) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.symbols.length; i++){
        if (this.state.symbols[i].symbol === symbol){
            const copyOfSymbolsList = [...this.state.symbols];
            if (copyOfSymbolsList[i].iconName === 'md-star') {
                copyOfSymbolsList[i].iconName = 'md-star-outline';
            } else {
                copyOfSymbolsList[i].iconName = 'md-star';    
            }

            this.setState({ symbols:copyOfSymbolsList });
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see above it basically just scrolls through the entire json array to find the appropriate row and then makes a copy of the list, changes the data and then sets state again.

The app isn't super fast maybe half a second delay before the icon changes on my pixel 2 and there is only 100 records in the list. Im a little worried if the list gets into the thousands of rows itll be really bad.

Is there a better/faster/simpler/more react-y way to solve this problem?

EDIT

This is the renderListItem function which calls the onPress function

```
renderListItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.onPressListItem(item.symbol)}
        >
            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <View style={{backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}}>
                    <Ionicons style={styles.listItemIcon} name={item.iconName} />
                </View>
                <View style={{backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}}>
                    <Text style={styles.listItem}>
                        {item.name.toUpperCase()} {item.symbol}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};
```

EDIT #2
This is the FlatList code.

```
<View style={styles.mainContainer}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.symbols}
                    keyExtractor= {(item, index) => item.symbol}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderListSeparator}
                    renderItem={this.renderListItem}
                />
            </View>
```

Comment: How do you get to this function? Isn’t there a way to reference the exact item that has been pressed?

Comment: I have edited the question with the call to onpress function

Comment: A function that returns JSX is a component.  You should create your own list item component that accepts the members of each item as a prop.  Then, in that component, conditionally render the icon based on the icon prop.  Now you aren’t rerendering the entire list every time one item changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guest your json structure is like this.

```
  the_data =  [
     {'iconName': 'xxx', 'symbol': '<i class="fa fa-items"></i>'}
    ]
```

You can access this structure by index, passing the index to the onPressListItem function.

```
renderListItem = ({ item }, index) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.onPressListItem(index)}
        >
            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <View style={{backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}}>
                    <Ionicons style={styles.listItemIcon} name={item.iconName} />
                </View>
                <View style={{backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}}>
                    <Text style={styles.listItem}>
                        {item.name.toUpperCase()} {item.symbol}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};
```

With this design you don't have to iterate your json.

```
onPressListItem = ( index ) => {
   the_dataobj = the_data[index];
   the_dataobj.iconName = 'md-start';
   if (the_dataobj.iconName === 'md-start'){
     the_dataobj.iconName = 'md-start_outline';
   }
   //you don't need a extra else here, is in-necesarry
   the_data[index] = the_dataobj;
   //set state ... do more
}
```

BTW: This is have nothing to do with react, the correct design of your workflow should be independent of the framework library.

Happy Codding!!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I get an error that says index is undefined???

Comment: found it...should be renderListItem = ({ item , index}) => {

Answer (score 0):

For those of you reading, the accepted answer did not update the rendered list properly on screen. So the actual working code for me is below. Im pretty sure its because the accepted answer did not use the this.setState function to write the values back to the array.

Also the if then else needs to have an else in it because when the user taps the same row twice i want it to reverse its changes.

All that being said, the updates are still very slow. About the same speed as it was when using the for loop in the question. Not sure why.

```
onPressListItem = ( index ) => {
        const copyOfSymbolsList = [...this.state.symbols];
        thePressedSymbol = copyOfSymbolsList[index];

        if (thePressedSymbol.iconName === 'md-star') {
            thePressedSymbol.iconName = 'md-star-outline';
        }else{
            thePressedSymbol.iconName = 'md-star';
        }
        copyOfSymbolsList[index] = thePressedSymbol;
        this.setState({ symbols:copyOfSymbolsList });
    }
```